# DataTable Select in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm debugging a Silverlight app, and running into an issue where an index of the array is out of bounds. I am not familiar enough with the syntax of the DataTable.Select statement, and the developer of the app is out of town for the next 10 days.  The line

**searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]))[0]["VALUE"] = wildcardedSearchString;**

From the code below is where the the "index out of bounds occurs, this happens on the second iteration of "i", when i=1. I am not quit sure what the [0]["VALUE"] represents in this situation. If someone could explain what that represents in this string I would greatly appreciate it!

```
if (i < 2 || country != -1)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildcardedSearchString))
    {
        searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]))[0]["VALUE"] = wildcardedSearchString;

        MarkRequiredParametersForSearch(searchParamsTable);

        returnList = GetSearchResults(contactType, session, searchParamsTable, returnList,
            (int)searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]))[0]["FIELDNO"]);

        // Filter by authority type if necessary.
        if (authorityType != AuthorityType.Unknown)
        {
            var results = from EntitySearchResult result in returnList
                          where result.SubType == (int)authorityType
                          select result;
            if (results != null)
            {
                returnList = results.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the length of tableNumbers[] and fieldName[]? I bet one or both of them are only 1 element long...

Comment: Both tableNumbers and fieldName are set to the correct values when i=1; it seems to be the [0]["VALUE"] that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable.Search()` returns a `DataRow[]`, so the `[0]["VALUE"]` gets the value of the "VALUE" column from the first row returned by `Search`.

It can be re-written as:

```
DataRow[] foundRows searchParamsTable.Select(string.Format("TABLE = {0} AND FIELD = '{1}'", tableNumbers[i], fieldName[i]));
DataRow firstRow = foundRows[0];
firstRow["VALUE"] = wildcardedSearchString;
```

From your code example it looks like you have a couple of places where the index out of range exception:

1. tableNumbers only has one element
2. fieldName only has one element
3. `Search` returns zero rows.

Comment: Thanks! Both tableNumbers and fieldName contain values. So it must be that the search is returning zero row. I'll try your code suggestion.